# Outlook custom menu buttons

Tags: vba, outlook, menubar

i have 2 menu buttons that i want added in outlook menu after help menu. i made the code to add the buttons but it just adds 2 more buttons every time i reopen outlook even if the 2 menu buttons are there already . Any help is welcomed.

```
Function ToolBarExists(strName As String) As Boolean
Dim tlbar As commandBar
    For Each tlbar In ActiveExplorer.CommandBars
     If tlbar.Name = strName Then
        ToolBarExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next tlbar
End Function

Sub TBarExistsbutton1()
    If ToolBarExists("button1") Then
        If ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("button1").Visible = True Then
            ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("button1").Visible = False
        Else
            ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("button1").Visible = True
        End If
    Else
        Call a123
    End If

End Sub
Sub TBarExistsbutton2()
    If ToolBarExists("button2") Then
        If ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("button2").Visible = True Then
            ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("button2").Visible = False
        Else
            ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("button2").Visible = True
        End If
    Else
        Call a1234
    End If
    End Sub

Sub a123()
Dim outl As Object
Dim msg As Object
Set outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim objBar As Office.commandBar
Dim objButton As Office.commandBarButton
Set objBar = Application.ActiveWindow.CommandBars("Menu Bar")
Set objButton = objBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
    With objButton
    .caption = "button1"
    .onAction = "macro1"
    .faceId = 487
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
End With
End Sub

Sub a1234()
Dim outl As Object
Dim msg As Object
Set outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim objBar As Office.commandBar
Dim objButton As Office.commandBarButton
Set objBar = Application.ActiveWindow.CommandBars("Menu Bar")
Set objButton = objBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
With objButton
    .caption = "button2"
    .onAction = "macro2"
    .faceId = 487
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When do you use Function ToolBarExists(strName As String) As Boolean?

Comment: Hi, that function should check for existing toolbars and i have about 10. it should check by name of the toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2010. If Visible works for you incorporate it in a similar manner.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TBarExistsbutton1()

    Dim cbControlCount As Long
    Dim button1Found As Boolean
    Dim j As Long

    If ToolBarExists("Menu Bar") Then

        cbControlCount = ActiveWindow.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls.count
        Debug.Print " There are " & cbControlCount & " controls in " & "Menu Bar"

        For j = 1 To cbControlCount
            Debug.Print ActiveWindow.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls(j).Caption
            If ActiveWindow.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls(j).Caption = "button1" Then
                button1Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If button1Found = False Then a123

    Else
        Debug.Print "Menu Bar does not exist."
        a123

    End If

End Sub
```